# Movimentar Imagens com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de um exemplo de como poderia movimentar uma imagem HTML usando JavaScript. Por Exemplo a Imagem esta numa posição, ao tocar um botao ele se movimente.Obrigado!

Comment: [Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) é uma excelente opção para isso. Este [exemplo](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/) bem básico mostra o deslocamento de uma figura.

Answer (score 4):

Já que não sei se você quer somente um botão para movimentar para somente um lado,tenho um exemplo movimentando aos 4 lados com 4 botões,segue o código :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo of changing position of an Image in JavaScript</title>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
<!--
function move_img(str) {
var step=50; // change this to different step value
switch(str){
case "down":
var x=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
x= x + step;
document.getElementById('i1').style.top= x + "px";
break;

case "up":
var x=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
x= x -step;
document.getElementById('i1').style.top= x + "px";
break;

case "left":
var y=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
y= y - step;
document.getElementById('i1').style.left= y + "px";
break;

case "right":
var y=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
y= y + step;
document.getElementById('i1').style.left= y + "px";
break;
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src=images/help.jpg id='i1' style="position:absolute; left: 500; top: 100;">
<br><br><br><br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('up') value='Up'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('left') value='Left'>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('right') value='right'>
<br>
<input type=button onClick=move_img('down') value='down'>
<br><br> Return to <a href=image-move.php>image move tutorial</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Exemplo deste código funcionando :** http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/image-move-demo.php

> OBS : Você também pode caso quiser que a imagem se mova mais ou até menos, mudar na variável `step` aonde `50` é o quanto ela irá mover.

Comment: Seguindo seu exemplo, coloquei no jsfiddle, assim fica mais fácil de ver os códigos separados https://jsfiddle.net/fb00t8Lq/1/ :)

Comment: @AdemílsonF.Tonato Obrigado amigo,vou colocar também na resposta se você não se importar :)

Comment: Sinta-se a vontade ;)